# Is this question off topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-request

[How to address the issue of a senior coworker pushing the use of undocumented standards](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/75859/16)

The original title was troublesome but the actual question asked was something that the workplace professionals should be able to help address, was focused enough for an answer, and seems to me to be on topic.

Answer (score 2):

It had 3 reopen votes already - now it's open.